# Unable to show more than four complaints on screen at the moment. How do I change the html or css to fit more?

Tags: html, css, django, django-views, django-templates

Right now when in my system the user can enter around four complaints or putting it simplay at the most only four complaints show up in a proper order. The fifth complaint shows up in the wrong place like this:

[image]

What should i change in my css or html so that when someone enters the fifth complaint the middle cntainer increases and a card shows up below the others as well? right now I am using four different css for four cards so that is the problem. How do I change it to fit this functionality?

html:

```
<!-- Middle Container -->
    <div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">My Complaints</h1>
        <p class="all-comp-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

        {%for c in complaint %}
        <a href="{% url 'Complaint' c.pk %}" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-{{forloop.counter0}}">
                <p style="color: #D37A19; margin-left: -130px; margin-top: -5px;">Report number:</p>
                <p class="history-level-1">{{c.reportnumber}}</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">{{c.event_type}}</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">{{c.event_text|truncatechars:85}}</p>
            </div>
        </a> {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

css:

```
.middle-complaint-con {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 650px;
        left: 204px;
        top: 57px;
        background: #FDF8F4;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
        border-radius: 30px;
    }

.comp-con-0 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 11px 8px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 160px;
        top: 190px;
        background: #FFEEDB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
.comp-con-1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 160px;
        top: 400px;
        background: #FFEEDB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
.comp-con-2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 610px;
        top: 190px;
        background: #FFEEDB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
.comp-con-3 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px 9px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
        left: 610px;
        top: 400px;
        background: #FFEEDB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the `complaint` variable has got only 4.

Comment: No, i haven't actually. I am a beginner in css and I don't know how that works. Could you please tell me how that could be implemented in this?

Comment: No, the complaint variable can go up to any number, but as the css is only available for the initial four compaints the fifth complaint is seen at the top left corner and not in a card format

Comment: I personally would set it up into rows, so that each row gets its own `<div>`, then use the templating engine to populate those divs

Comment: Could you show me how to do that? I did not properly understand that.

Comment: something like this: `<div id="complaints"><div class="row"><Report#1 /><Report#2 /></div><div class="row"><Report#3 /><Report#4 /></div></div>`, substituting `<Report#1 />` for the first report, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can add pagination with the help of django.
What you can do is create a link downwards which says view all complaints.

A user can have than 5 complaints like 6, 7, 100 or so you can create a dedicated page for it and use pagination to display 4 complaints at each page
[Using pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/)